# How to obtain all the nodes in a path from breadth first search of a graph

Tags: java, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

Suppose we have a simple graph like this:

[image]

It was easy to find a path from start node to end node with depth-first search, but I got stuck while trying to do the same thing with breadth-first search. My code is as follows:

```
public List<String> getPathBreadth(String name1, String name2) {
    Node node1 = getNode(name1);
    Node node2 = getNode(name2);
    if (node1 == null || node2 == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return getPathBreadth(node1, node2, new HashSet<String>(), new LinkedList<Node>());
}

private List<String> getPathBreadth(Node start, Node destination, HashSet<String> visited, Queue<Node> queue) {
    List<String> path = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (start == destination) {
        path.add(start.name);
        return path;
    }
    visited.add(start.name);
    queue.offer(start);
    while (queue.size() > 0) {
        Node cur = queue.poll();
        for (String friend : cur.friends) {
            if (visited.contains(friend)) {
                continue;
            }
            visited.add(friend);
            if (getNode(friend) == destination) {
                path.add(friend); // I got the final node, I could also add cur, but how do I get the previous nodes along the path
                return path;
            }
            queue.offer(getNode(friend));
        }
    }
    return path;
}
```

Suppose we want to go from `John` to `Linda`, so I wish to return something like `[Linda, Robert, John]` or `[Linda, Patrica, John]`, but the best I can do for now is get the last and second to the last nodes. In this case they are `Linda` and `Robert`. How do I get all the previous nodes along the path?

Answer (score 0):

To make the code usable please add `Node` definition, and tree (test data).
(see [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ).
I think the problem is here :

```
if (getNode(friend) == destination) {
                path.add(friend); 
                return path;
 }
```

The only node you add to the path in the last one. Try:

```
path.add(friend);     
if (getNode(friend) == destination) {                
     return path; //or better: break;
}
```

Unfortunately I can't run and check it.

A side note: 
`visited.add(friend)`  Returns true if this set did not already contain friend
so:

```
if (visited.contains(friend)) {
   continue;
}
visited.add(friend);
```

can be replaced with

```
 if (! visited.add(friend)) {
     continue;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing up the side note. I was able to solve the problem by using a map that maps the node at the current level to a list of nodes at the previous level, so if a path exists, I just need to go back by retrieving the node from the map one by one.

Comment: The side note is just that. Could you relate to the solution proposed ? Also consider posting an answer to your question.